# Fields of `sqlalchemy.types.Enum` in Graphene-SQLAlchemy mapped to strings in GraphQL schema

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, graphql, graphene-python

Consider the following enum class:

```
import enum
class CoverTitleColor(enum.Enum):
    YELLOW = "yellow"
    RED = "red"
    BLUE = "blue"
    ORANGE = "orange"
    WHITE = "white"
    PURPLE = "purple"
```

set as an SQLAlchemy ORM field as such:

```
class Book(Base, OrmBaseMixin):
    __tablename__ = "books"

    book_id = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.types.Integer(),
        primary_key=True,
    )
    ...
    cover_title_color = sqlalchemy.Column(
        sqlalchemy.types.Enum(CoverTitleColor),
        nullable=False
    )
```

and exposed to Graphene through:

```
class TypeBook(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
```

However, when introspecting `TypeBook` through GraphQL through the following query:

```
{
  __type(name: "TypeBook") {
    name
    fields {
      name
      type {
        name
        kind
        ofType {
          name
          kind
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the `coverTitleColor` field is interpreted as a string:

```
{
  "name": "coverTitleColor",
  "type": {
    "name": null,
    "kind": "NON_NULL",
    "ofType": {
      "name": "String",
      "kind": "SCALAR"
    }
  }
},
```

when querying out that field, e.g., through:

```
query {
  books(year: 1990) {
    coverTitleColor
  } 
}
```

the result is indeed a string like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "books": [
      {
        "coverTitleColor": "CoverTitleColor.YELLOW"
      },
      {
        "coverTitleColor": "CoverTitleColor.RED"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I missing something? Is this the expected behaviour?

> The full working code can be found under https://github.com/somada141/demo-graphql-sqlalchemy-falcon/tree/issue-graphene-sqlalchemy-135
>
> This question has also been posted as a GH issue under https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-sqlalchemy/issues/135

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm too late but what worked for me was injecting the str method to the Enum class. So you can write the `CoverTitleColor` it like this:

```
class CoverTitleColor(str, enum.Enum):
```

It worked for queries and mutations.